# WebException when trying to use Bing Translate API

Tags: c#, bing, translate

I'm attempting to translate some English text to Chinese using Bing Translate's API.

My code is essentially what was provided on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512437), albeit with a few modifications.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AutoTranslate2
{
    public class Translator
    {
        private string authToken;

        public Translator(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            AdmAccessToken admToken;

            AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("clientId", "client secret");

            admToken = admAuth.GetAccessToken();
            DateTime tokenReceived = DateTime.Now;
            this.authToken = "Bearer " + admToken.access_token;
        }

        public string TranslateMethod(
            string text,
            string inputLang = "en",
            string outputLang = "zh-CHS", // Chinese, simplified ('zh-CHT' is traditional Chinese)
            string inputType = "text/html",
            string outputType = "general")
        {
            // Add TranslatorService as a service reference, Address:http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc
            TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient client = new TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();
            //Set Authorization header before sending the request
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestProperty.Method = "POST";
            httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", this.authToken);

            // Creates a block within which an OperationContext object is in scope.
            string translationResult;
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
                //Keep appId parameter blank as we are sending access token in authorization header.
                translationResult = client.Translate("", "<p>" + text + "</p>", inputLang, outputLang, inputType, outputType);
            }
            return translationResult;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class AdmAccessToken
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string scope { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdmAuthentication
    {
        public static readonly string DatamarketAccessUri = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
        private string clientId;
        private string clientSecret;
        private string request;

        public AdmAuthentication(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
            //If clientid or client secret has special characters, encode before sending request
            this.request = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));
        }

        public AdmAccessToken GetAccessToken()
        {
            return HttpPost(DatamarketAccessUri, this.request);
        }

        private AdmAccessToken HttpPost(string DatamarketAccessUri, string requestDetails)
        {
            //Prepare OAuth request 
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(DatamarketAccessUri);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestDetails);
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (webResponse)
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
                //Get deserialized object from JSON stream
                AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and somewhere else in my code, I do...

```
Translator t = new Translator(client_id, secret);
string output = t.TranslateMethod(text);
```

However, the code always returns an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at AutoTranslate2.AdmAuthentication.HttpPost(String DatamarketAccessUri, String requestDetails) in C:\Users\Deflect\AutoTranslate2\AutoTranslate2\Translate.cs:line 102
   at AutoTranslate2.AdmAuthentication.GetAccessToken() in C:\Users\Deflect\AutoTranslate2\AutoTranslate2\Translate.cs:line 87
   at AutoTranslate2.Translator..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret) in C:\Users\Deflect\AutoTranslate2\AutoTranslate2\Translate.cs:line 26
   at AutoTranslate2.Chinese.Parse(String rawText) in C:\Users\Deflect\AutoTranslate2\AutoTranslate2\Parse.cs:line 68
   at AutoTranslate2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Deflect\AutoTranslate2\AutoTranslate2\Program.cs:line 19
```

I'll be the first to admit I really don't know what my code is doing, since I mostly copied and pasted from MSDN -- does anybody know why my code is returning an exception, and how I can get it to work?

Comment: Your code is throwing an exception because you have submitted an invalid request to the server. You should get a program like Fiddler, look at the structure of the request being sent, and then compare that to the structure that the service requires. If there are differences, adjust your code to eliminate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was this line:

```
AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("clientId", "client secret");
```

I forgot to swap the strings in the examples with the actual variables.